# Why doesn't Mathematica integrate this?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to do this integral in Mathematica:

```
f[x_] := A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]*DiracDelta[v - Abs[x]]
Integrate[f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

It just writes out the integral.

This is weird since I integrated this with no problem:

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[(2/pi)]*(x^2/b^3)*Exp[-x^2/(2*b^2)]*DiracDelta[en - m*x^2/2]
Integrate[f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

My guess is that it has to do with the absolute value `Abs` in `DiracDelta` but I don't know why that should be a problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is really weird! I'll note that integrating from `-Infinity` to `0` and adding it to the integral from `0` to `Infinity` works, and that explicit exact values of `v` are okay *except* for `0` (and substituting machine numbers for `v` also leaves it in unevaluated form). I'm not sure why Mathematica can't figure out how to just...add the two sides of the integrals. Really weird stuff.

Comment: Simpler example: `Integrate[ Exp[-x^2/(2)]*DiracDelta[v - Abs[x]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]`.  @thorimur's example may be reduced to `Integrate[Exp[-x^2/(2)]*DiracDelta[v - Abs[x]], {x, -Infinity, 0, Infinity}]`

Comment: I think the answer lies in `Assumptions -> v > 0` and `Assumptions -> v < 0`.  I wouldn't expect `Integrate` to produce a `Piecewise` solution.  Maybe a `ConditionalExpression`, but, alas, it does not.

Comment: I thought about this a bit and: The dirac delta function is a distribution, not a function, and it works differently under coordinate rescalings. That is, if δ(x) is multiplied against something in an integral, and you u-substitute x=f(t), well, we have to preserve the function value; so to cancel out the f'(t) from dx = f'(t) dt, we need δ(x) = δ(f(t))/f'(t). However, |x| is not differentiable at x=0. This is only relevant when v-|x|=0 at x=0, i.e., when v=0. So, Mathematica might be trying to change variables so that the argument of δ is atomic, but here can't bc of the undefined derivative.

Comment: But, I'm not sure—I'll need to think about it more!

Comment: @BobHanlon You need only `v` to be positive. (But it gives the incorrect answer when `v <= 0`.)

Comment: @thorimur Yes, `Integrate` tries to divide by `f'[±v]`.   For `Abs[x]`, it replaces it by `Sqrt[x^2]` in this integral, but its derivative is still undefined at `x == 0`.

Comment: Does replacing `f[x_] := A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]*DiracDelta[v - Abs[x]]` with `f[x_] := A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]*DiracDelta[(v - x)*(v + x)]` do any better?

Comment: @thorimur:  I think you're right about the integral not being well-defined when $v = 0$;  see my comment on Ulrich's answer below.  (Also, you're aware that MathJax works in comments, right?)

Comment: I don't find any inttegral of such kind in math literature: e.g. see W. Rudin, Functional Analysis and [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function) with references there .

Answer (score 5):

We get different answers depending on whether `v` is positive, negative, or zero:

```
Integrate[
 A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]*DiracDelta[v - Abs[x]], {x, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, Assumptions -> v > 0]
```

> ```
> (*  2 A E^(-((M v^2)/(2 kb T)))  *)
> ```

```
Integrate[
 A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]*DiracDelta[v - Abs[x]], {x, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, Assumptions -> v < 0]
```

> ```
> (*  0  *)
> ```

```
Integrate[
 A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]*DiracDelta[v - Abs[x]], {x, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, Assumptions -> v == 0]
```

> ```
> (* unevaluated (same as input) *)
> ```

Tried it with `RealAbs`, but no go (it tries to divide by the derivative at `x ==0`, which leads to the errors).

```
Integrate[
 A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]*DiracDelta[v - RealAbs[x]], {x, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, Assumptions -> v == 0]
```

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.
> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.
>
> ```
> (* unevaluated (same as input) *)
> ```

I don't think `Integrate` deals with all those cases in one go.

Comment: So this is correct except for the v=0 case?

Comment: @chris Yes, I believe the integral is unproblematic for $v \ne 0$ and `Integrate` gets it right with the appropriate `Assumptions`.  I'm not sure how the integral is defined for $v = 0$. `Integrate[A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]*DiracDelta[Abs[x]], {x, -Infinity, 0, Infinity}]` gives an interesting answer.

Comment: I don't find any inttegral of such kind in math literature: e.g. see W. Rudin, Functional Analysis and [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function) with references there.

Comment: @user64494 [Hashimoto 1993](https://doi.org/10.1016/0893-9659(93)90099-9) deals with this situation -- I am unfamiliar with this paper, but it proposes to resolve exactly this type of problem, which the author says arises in gauge theory. I am also unfamiliar with any further research. I'm not surprised it is not part of standard developments of the delta function. Encyclopedias do not catalog every leaf in the forest, only the more important features.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica has problem to handle the `Abs` inside the argument of `DiracDelta` (Thanks to the answer of @MichaelE2)

Knowing `DiracDelta[v-Abs[x]]=DiracDelta[v-x]+DiracDelta[v+x]` Mathematica evaluates the case `v!=0`

```
Integrate[A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]*(DiracDelta[v - x ] +DiracDelta[v + x ]), {x, -Infinity, Infinity},Assumptions -> v != 0]
(*ConditionalExpression[2 A E^(-((M v^2)/(2 kb T))), v \[Element] Reals]*)
```

**wrong assumption:**

Thanks to @MichaelSeifert
Case `v==0` because `DiracDelta[-Abs[x]]==DiracDelta[x]` follows to

**wrong result:**

```
Integrate[A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]*(DiracDelta[ x ] ), {x, -Infinity,Infinity},Assumptions -> v != 0]
(*A*)
```

**addendum**

The case `v==0` follows from `Integrate[A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]* DiracDelta[-Abs[x]], {x, - Infinity}, Infinity} ]==`

```
Integrate[A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]* DiracDelta[-x], {x, 0, Infinity} ] +Integrate[A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]*  DiracDelta[ x], {x, -Infinity, 0} ]`
(*2 A - 2 A HeavisideTheta[0]*)
```

This result (see comment @MichaelE2 ) is disappointing because  `HeavisideTheta[0]` is undefined.

A workaround might be the use of a limit definition of `DiracDelta`

```
dirac = Function[{x, \[CurlyEpsilon]},1/Sqrt[2 Pi \[CurlyEpsilon]] Exp[-(x^2/(2 \[CurlyEpsilon]))]]  (* \[CurlyEpsilon]->0 *)
Integrate[dirac[x, \[CurlyEpsilon]] , {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> \[CurlyEpsilon] > 0] 
(* 1 *)
```

The case `v==0` follows to

```
Integrate[A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]* dirac[ -x, \[CurlyEpsilon] ], {x, 0,Infinity} ] +Integrate[A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]*  dirac[ x, \[CurlyEpsilon] ],{x, -Infinity,0} ]
(*ConditionalExpression[A/(Sqrt[M/(kb T) + 1/\[CurlyEpsilon]] Sqrt[\[CurlyEpsilon]]),Re[M/(kb T) + 1/\[CurlyEpsilon]] > 0]*)
```

limit `\[CurlyEpsilon]->0` gives  `A` as the result of the case `v==0`

Comment: I'm not sure about your last statement there.  Formally, $\delta(f(x)) = \delta(x - x_0)/f'(x_0)$ if $f$ is a differentiable function with $f(x_0) = 0$.  But if $f(x) = - |x|$, then $f'(0)$ is not well-defined.

Comment: I can get `A` for `v=0`, as well as `2 A - 2 A HeavisideTheta[0]`,  but my concern was the same as @Michael, whether $\int g(x) \delta(f(x)) \, dx$ is well-defined when $f$ has singular points. I'm not familiar with the theory in this case.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That HeavisideTheta result for $v = 0$ is interesting. If we let `HeavisideTheta[0]` run from 1 down to 0, then `2 A - 2 A HeavisideTheta[0]` runs from 0 (the answer for $v = 0^-$) up to $2A$ (the answer for $v = 0^+$).

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Good point, I assumed symmetric DiracDelta[x], probably wrong assumption.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert See my modified answer!

Comment: I don't find any inttegral of such kind in math literature: e.g. see W. Rudin, Functional Analysis and [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function) with references there.

Comment: Wikipedia "dirac delta function" gives a link to "Encyclopedia of Mathematics, EMS Press"

Answer (score 0):

**final answer**

`DiracDelta[v-Abs[x]]==DiracDelta[Abs[x]-v]` only contributes to the integral if the argument `v-Abs[x]` becomes zero. That's only possible if **`v>=0`**!

The integral evaluates to

```
Integrate[A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]* DiracDelta[-x - v] , {x, -Infinity, 0},Assumptions -> v >= 0] + 
Integrate[A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]* DiracDelta[x - v] , {x, 0, Infinity },Assumptions -> v >= 0]
(*2 A E^(-((M v^2)/(2 kb T))) HeavisideTheta[v]*)
```

Result is ok for case `v>0` but differs from case `v==0`

```
Integrate[A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]*DiracDelta[-x], {x, -Infinity, 0}] + 
Integrate[A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]*DiracDelta[x], {x, 0, Infinity} ]
(*2 A - 2 A HeavisideTheta[0]*)
```

Confirmation of the results is done using limit sequence for the DiracDelta-function:

```
dirac = Function[{x, eps}, Exp[-(x^2/(2 eps))]/Sqrt[2 Pi eps]] ;(* eps->0*)
Integrate[  dirac[x, eps], {x, -Infinity, Infinity},Assumptions -> eps > 0]
(*1*)
```

The integration gives a  symbolical result depending on `eps`

```
Integrate[A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]* dirac[v + x, eps] , {x, -Infinity, 0},Assumptions -> {eps > 0, v >= 0}] + 
Integrate[A*Exp[-x^2*M/(2*kb*T)]* dirac[x - v, eps] , {x, 0, Infinity },Assumptions -> {eps > 0, v >= 0}]
(*ConditionalExpression[(A E^(-((M v^2)/(2 eps M + 2 kb T))) (1 + 
Erf[v/(Sqrt[2] eps Sqrt[1/eps + M/(kb T)])]))/(Sqrt[eps] Sqrt[1/eps + M/(kb T)]), eps Re[M/(kb T)] > -1]*)
```

limit yields the final answer

```
A E^(-((M v^2)/(2 kb T))) (1 + Erf[v/Sqrt[2] ])
```

for the unknown integral (case v>=0 ) including case `v==0`(result `A`)!